# Drill parent child BusinessObjects

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am facing a problem that I cannot solve. I have the 3 tables below:

- **Seller** : `idSeller / idGroup / sellerName`
- **Groups**: `idGroup / Level / idGroupParent`
- **Sales**: `idCommercial / Sales`

I have several levels of groups from 1 to 5, that would give me as a flowchart of sellers.

I wish I could have a report BO with drill, be able to leave the commercial level 1 then navigate in the sub levels to see their sales.

I cannot model it correctly under universe design tools.
I hope I have been clear in my question.

Hoping for a little help... Thank you very much.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I try to put 4 alias tables on my Groups table to represent each level, but I can not get my sales under each level.